# Google indexing only specific domain

Tags: url, dns, seo, indexing

I have a problem with Google indexing.
The thing is that I have several domains (language mutations) example: `www.example.com`, `www.example.co.uk`, `www.example.de`.

So each site has its own language and its own SEO links, example:

- `search/en-us/building/window/77/1/`
- `search/en-gb/building/window/77/1/`
- `search/de-de/gebaude/fenster/77/1/`

Now Google is indexing those SEO url links with wrong domains like `www.example.co.uk/search/de-de/gebaude/fenster/77/1/` which should obviously be correctly: `www.example.de/search/de-de/gebaude/fenster/77/1/`

Every language is bound to its own domain so there is no possibility that EN-GB leads to a German language mutation on `www.example.de`

I am open to all advice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing happens.  Its easier than you think to create a bad link.  One hard coded domain name in the wrong place and you have a link to somewhere you didn't mean to link.  Once Googlebot finds a site served on a wrong domain, it will crawl the whole thing.  Even if you are correct, that you would **never** create such a link, maybe there is an external link created by a user in which they got the domain name confused.

The technique that you need to apply is called **URL canonicalization**.  You have two options:

- Put the rel canonical meta tag on each of your pages.  `search/de-de/gebaude/fenster/77/1/`  would have a canonical URL in the tag which has the correct domain: `http://www.example.de/search/de-de/gebaude/fenster/77/1/`  You'd have to make sure that the domain in the canonical tag is the `.de` domain whether that page were accessed on the `.co.uk` domain or on the `.de` domain.
- Use 301 redirects to correct any URLs that are wrong.  Have your server detect that a domain name is wrong.  301 redirect `www.example.co.uk/search/de-de/gebaude/fenster/77/1/` to `www.example.de/search/de-de/gebaude/fenster/77/1/`

Another random piece of SEO advice:  I would remove the word "search" from your URLs.  Google doesn't like to index site search results in its search results.  I've seen cases where it assumes that the word "search" in the URL indicates that the page shouldn't be indexed for this reason.

Comment: Checked everything and did by your answer, working much better now, thank you!